# How do I install an app with system-rights on a non-rooted smartphone?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, installation, root-access

I would like to install logcat as system-app on a non-rooted phone.

Is that possible (using adb without root-access)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A system app has to be either installed by root or signed with the same key that signed the ROM image.

Comment: So `adb install` will not work in that case?

Comment: `adb install` just installs an app in the usual way. It doesn't make an app a system app.